# Sizeof array in php not working in the for loop

Tags: php, html, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to make some variables through an array in the for loop. The problem I came across is the for loop and defining the second parameter (sizeof array, or count). If in this place I put number 4, the whole script works, but if I put $length - it gives me nothing.

**HTML**

```
<form action="proceed.php" method="post"> 
<textarea name="que[1]"></textarea>
<textarea name="que[2]"></textarea>
<textarea name="que[3]"></textarea><br/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO"><br/> 
</form>
```

**PROCEED.PHP**

```
<?php
$bla = "";
$question = array();
$length = count($question);

for($j=1; $j<$length; $j++) {
    $question = $_POST['que'];

if($question[$j] != "") {
    $bla .= $j.'This is good<br/><br/>';
}}
echo $bla;
?>
```

Comment: You don't need the `foreach` now, if `$_POST['que']` is already an array. Just copy it. (Or rather don't; redundant.)

Comment: $length is zero as $question is an empty array at the time count($question) is put into $length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating an empty array and then counting the size of it. Why would you expect anything but a count of zero?

What you really want is the size of the `que` array:

```
$length = count($_POST['que']);
```

But that makes some your code unnecessary since this is already an array.

```
for($j=1; $j<$length; $j++) {
  // $question = $_POST['que']; UNNECESSARY 
  if($_POST['que'][$j] != "") {
    $bla .= $j.'This is good<br/><br/>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$bla = "";
$question = $_POST['que'];
$length = count($question);

for($j=1; $j<$length; $j++) {    
    if($question[$j] != "") {
        $bla .= $j.'This is good<br/><br/>';
    }
}
echo $bla;
?>
```